# Backbone.js: Dynamically adding events not firing

Tags: events, backbone.js

I am trying around with Backbone.js and get along so far, but I have got a problem.

Lets say I got a root element and a child element.

When the document loads, I create 3 "root" instances. The root instance appends a  tag.
Each root instance creates one child instance which creates a

tag in the ul tag.

Now I would like the child instance to attach and onclick event to the

tag. Unfortunately, it won't work.

I created a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fluxo/sEjE5/17/

```
var child = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template('<li>Item '+count+'</li>'),
    events: {
        'click li': function() {
         alert('listitem Click Child Element');   
        }
    },
    initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll('render');  
     this.render();   
    }, render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template())
    }
});

var root = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template('<div><h3>List</h3><p /><ul></ul><hr />'),
    events: {
        'click li': function() {
         alert('listitem Click - Root Element');   
        }
    },
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll('render');
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        $('body').append(this.el);
        var item = new child();
        this.$el.find('ul').append(item.$el.html());

    }
});
```

The events created in the root element will fire, but not the ones in the child element.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing two things wrong.

First of all, your `child` is an `<li>`, it doesn't contain an `<li>`:

```
template: _.template('<li>Item '+count+'</li>'),
events: {
    'click li': ...
},
```

so your `click li` event won't do anything. Events are bound to the [view's `el` using `delegate`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents):

> **delegateEvents** `delegateEvents([events])`
>
> Uses jQuery's `delegate` function to provide declarative callbacks for DOM events within a view. [...] Omitting the `selector` causes the event to be bound to the view's root element (`this.el`).

So if you want to bind a click handler directly to the view's `el` rather than one of its children, you want to leave out the selector:

```
events: {
    'click': ...
}
```

The next problem is that you're not actually inserting the `child` element into the DOM, you're copying the HTML:

```
this.$el.find('ul').append(item.$el.html());
```

By appending `item.$el.html()` instead of `item.el`, you're grabbing the correct HTML as a string and inserting that HTML but you lose the events in the process; the events are bound to the DOM object, `item.el`, not to the HTML string. You can fix this by appending `item.el`:

```
this.$el.find('ul').append(item.el);
// Or you could say, the two approaches are the same
this.$('ul').append(item.el);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/K76JM/ (or http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/kFxHQ/)

Comment: Thanks, the item.$el.html() did mess it up. Don't know why I did that, but now it works like a charme :) Thanks for this valuable tip!

Comment: @mu is too short up vote because your answer solved one of my issues. thanks